# How can I update an adapter of an Activity from other Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

Problem: Activity A is a `ListView` that contains a `ListAdapter`, and clicking in any item of the adapter leads to activity B. Activity B has a button that fetches a new item (or several)  from the web (using an `AsyncTask`) and adds it to the list displayed by activity A when pressed. That operation from B is not blocked by a `ProgressDialog`, so the user can move back to A before the `AsyncTask` that B started finishes fetching the data.

So I need a way of updating the adapter of A from B.

I have a class C with static data displayed in the `ListView` by A. When the button at B is pressed, it adds that value to C. That class also has the adapter from A as a static field, but I think that this leaks the memory from the `Context`, and that is bad. My first idea of fixing this was removing the static adapter from C and every time A `onResume()` (and if the data on the adapter is different from what I have at C), I load the data from C again into the adapter and `notifyDatasetChanged()`. Well, it works most of the time, but if the user goes back to A from B before B fetches the data from the web, then the adapter does not update, since the `onResume()` came before the data is fetched.

Question: Is there a better way of updating the adapter of A from B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't save static references to the adapter. It will indeed leak memory and behave badly.

It appears I misunderstood the first time. Here is an updated answer:

**First solution**

The prettiest solution is to implement a content provider for the data storage and query that content provider in both A and B. Update the data in B using contentProvider.insert()
and read the data using contentProvider.query() returning for example a SQLiteCursor if it is backed by database or a MatrixCursor if you just save it in memory in the content provider.

The basic steps (without CursorLoader):

1. In onCreate of A you register yourself as a contentobserver using `ContentResolver.registerContentObserver(uri, true, this)` where uri is an URI using some scheme you set.
2. In onCreate of A you get the data by querying the contentprovider using `ContentResolver.query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder)` where projection, selection, selectionArgs and sortOrder can be what fits your contentprovider (maybe null). Uri refers to the data you want to query and is your choice.
3. When data is loaded in B you call `ContentResolver.insert()`. In `insert` of your contentprovider you call `ContentResolver.notifyChange (Uri uri, null, null)` where uri is the URI you used in step 1.
4. Implement onChange(boolean selfChange) in A and requery the content provider when it is called.

Note that you will not need to call registerContentObserver at all if you use CursorLoaders!
It will receive the new cursor in the loader since it has automatic requery when you notify change.

**Second solution**
A less pretty solution is to implement a singleton object that handles the data.
Something like:

1. Implement the class

   ```
   public class DataHolder {
       private static DataHolder sDataHolder;

       private String data = ""; // Data represented by string.
       public DataHolder getInstance() {
           if (sDataHolder == null) {
               sDataHolder = new DataHolder()
           }
           return sDataHolder;
       }

       private DataHolder() {} // Hidden constructor

       public void setData(final String data) {
           mData = data;

           for (DataListener listener: mDataListeners) {
               listener.onDataChanged(mData);
           }
       }

       public void registerListener(DataListener listener) {
          mDataListeners.add(listener);
       }

       public String unregisterListener(DataListener listener) {
          mDataListeners.remove(listener);
       }

       public String getData() {
          return mData;
       }

       public static interface DataListener {
           public void onDataChanged(String data);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Make A implement DataListener
3. Read and update the data in `onStart()` of DataListener to make sure that it is set if the change was done when B was alive using `DataHolder.getInstance().getData()`.
4. Register listener in A's onCreate/onStart using `DataHolder.getInstance().registerListener(this);` Let the listener update the data.
5. Unregister listener in A's onDestroy/onStop using `DataHolder.getInstance().unregisterListener(this)`
6. Set the data and signal any listener in B using `DataHolder.getInstance().setData(data)`

Also note that you can make the second solution fully thread safe by changing `void registerListener()` to `synchronized String registerListenerAndGetValue()` if you also make setValue synchronized.

**Old answer based on a misunderstanding**

My old answer for general result handling did not quite answer the question, but it was:

If you want to send data back to an activity A you should do the following:

1. Always start B with `startActivityForResult (Intent intent, int requestCode)`
2. Set the result when done in B using `setResult (int resultCode)`
3. Handle the result when you come back to A by implementing `onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)`

As an addition you could add so you only fetch data in A the first time by doing it only if `savedInstanceState == null` in for example onCreate().

Comment: The user could press the BACK button(and get a `RESULT_CANCEL` as a result code in `onActivityResult()`) while the data is still being fetch in activity B. How he will proceed in this case?

Comment: Exactly. The data at B is being fetched in an AsyncTask, and when it ends it sets the data at C. If the user press BACk from B, the activity would end, but the data would still be fetched in the AsyncTask.

Comment: I misunderstood the question. Sorry for that. I added two solutions in the edited answer.

Comment: Interesting solutions. What I have now most closely resembles what you described at your second solution. I'll try going in that direction and keep you informed if I succeded or not. Just a minor observation, I think that what you meant at 5 is "onStop/onDestroy", right?

Comment: Correct. Good luck and keep me posted. I guessed that your solution was similar to the second one. I mostly wrote it in case you overlooked something.

I realize that the contentprovider solution seems less intuitive and complicated at first, but it often the most effective solution and simple to extend and connect to other parts since it is the preferred framework solution.

Answer (score 0):

try calling `mListView.invalidate();`

****java-doc**

*Invalidate the whole view. If the view is visible, onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas) will be called at some point in the future. This must be called from a UI thread. To call from a non-UI thread, call postInvalidate()*.