# Android refresh listview adapter from another activity

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I Googled a lot, but can't find the proper answer.

I've got two **activities**. Each of that activities 'has' one **listview**.

Each of that listviews have a custom **ArrayAdapter**. So :

Activity 1 ---->  Listview 1  ------> custom ArrayAdapter 1

Activity 2 ---->  Listview 2  ------> custom ArrayAdapter 2

When I press a button in **Activity 1**, then it refreshes the **Listview 1** (it's adapter).

**The goal** is : I have to do a refresh on Listview 2 too that time. How can I achieve this ? I've read something about broadcasting, but didn't understand it well.

Thank You !

Comment: What type of content do you have in the adapters? I guess they share content.
If you share content between the adapters it is probably a matter of just notifying about the change as Waqas says.
Check out my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9333790/how-can-i-update-an-adapter-of-an-activity-from-other-activity/9333942#9333942 In essence you should not reference the actual adapter from other activities since it will lead to tight coupling and potential data leaks.

Comment: Thank you. I've read your answer. It's pretty awesome, but now I'm just learning the programming in Android, so now Waqas's way enough for me. Thank You !

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are in **Activity1**, it's useless to try to refresh **Activity2**'s listview as it's not visible. However, what you can do is, when the user is switched to **Activity2**, just call adapter's `notifyDataSetChanged()` in it's **onResume()** method and your **Activity2** will be refreshed.

Comment: I don't think it is the most proper way, but thanks, in this case it's enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

Add listView as global variable in each activity and make it public static.

Then, just call it when you need it.

e.g. in activity1, call the following to let the list in activity2 refresh

```
if(SecondActivity.listView != null)

    ((ArrayAdapter)SecondActivity.listView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetInvalidated();
```

Comment: its not compilable unless you make your listview static too. and doing so may lead to memory leaks.

Comment: Yes, but sometime users need to refresh the list on background receiver. Make the list public and static is the easier way to control it